# Python: How to initialize a list with generator function

Tags: python, generator

Let's say i have 2 following functions:

```
def get_items():
    items = []
    for i in xrange(2, 10):
        items.append(i)
    return items

def gen_items():
    for i in xrange(2, 10):
        yield i
```

I know i can use both of them in a for loop like this

```
for item in gen_items():
    do something
```

But now i need to initialize a variable as list, like this

```
mylist = get_items()
```

but with the generator function. Is there a way to do it without a for loop appending the items from generator?

Comment: `mylist = list( get_items() )`

Comment: `xrange` is already a generator by the way

Comment: [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange) returns an object which is lazy evaluated in Python 2 like the `range` function in Python 3. So if all your generator function is doing is iterate over the `xrange` object, then `list(xrange(2, 10))` will work beautifully.

Comment: @Farhan.K: I know, it was just example to explain my question, i don't really have any such function on my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list builtin will accept any iterator:

```
l = list(gen_items())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just directly create it using `list` which will handle iterating for you

```
>>> list(gen_items())
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```